# spring property substitution for test and production

Tags: spring

I ran into this for property substitution in spring

```
<context:property-placeholder location="esb-project-config.properties"/>
```

but unfortunately, we don't want this in the xml file as we want to re-use the file in our tests but swap in the test.properties file for test.  ie. we want to test all the production bindings but with properties that are suitable for test like localhost for instance.  How can we load the ApplicationContext but with different properties files?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the property-placeholder configuration in an extra spring xml configuration file.

For example:

- `applicationContext.xml` -- for the normal configration without any property-placeholder configuration
- `applicationContext-config.xml` -- contains only a property-placeholder that load the production config file.
- `testApplicationContext.xml`. This file `include`s the `applicationContext.xml` and uses a property-placeholder with an other properties file.

In a Web App you could load all production spring context files with this pattern `applicationContext*.xml`.

For the tests you need only to load `testApplicationContext.xml` this will include the normal config, but with other properties.

Answer (score 84):

several approaches:

---

### 1. 'Order' Property

in `src/main/resources/your-conf.xml`

```
<context:property-placeholder 
         location="classpath:esb-project-config.properties"
         order="1"/>
```

in `src/test/resources/your-test-config.xml`

```
<context:property-placeholder 
         location="classpath:esb-project-config.properties"
         order="0"/>
```

If you running your test with `src/test/resources` as a test classpath, the above will ensure to override `src/main/resources/esb-project-config.properties` with the `src/test/resources/esb-project-config.properties`.

This will override the whole `property-placeholder` though, so you would have to provide all the properties needed in your application in for this test `property-placeholder`. e.g.

```
<context:property-placeholder 
         location="classpath:esb-project-config.properties,
                   classpath:some-other-props-if-needed.properties"
         order="0"/>
```

---

### 2. PropertyOverrideConfigurer

```
 <context:property-override 
          location="classpath:esb-project-config.test.properties"/>
```

to override certain *individual* properties. Some examples [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer)

---

### 3. System Variables

You can use a prefix to control environment specific properties, this can be done by using system variables:

```
 <context:property-placeholder 
          location="${ENV_SYSTEM:dev}/esb-project-config.properties"/>
```

In this case it will always look under:

```
 <context:property-placeholder 
          location="dev/esb-project-config.properties"/>
```

**by default**, unless a `ENV_SYSTEM` system variable is set. If it is set to `qa`, for example, it will automatically look under:

```
 <context:property-placeholder 
          location="qa/esb-project-config.properties"/>
```

---

### 4. Spring Profiles

Another approach is to make beans profile specific. For example:

```
<beans profile="dev">
  <context:property-placeholder 
           location="esb-project-config.dev.properties"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="qa">
  <context:property-placeholder 
           location="esb-project-config.qa.properties"/>
</beans>
```

The appropriate `esb-project-config` will loaded depending on a profile set. For example this will load `esb-project-config.dev.properties`:

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles( "dev" );
ctx.load( "classpath:/org/boom/bang/config/xml/*-config.xml" );
ctx.refresh();
```

---

- NOTE: "System Variables" and "System Profiles" approaches are usually used to switch between different *environments* rather than just "dev <==> test" in dev mode, but still are useful capabilities to be aware of.

Comment: I tried the 4) Spring profile part and it doesn't seem to work. I guess you can't use custom namespaces inside <beans> ?

Comment: You can declare the placeholders normally or use:     <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config_${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />

Comment: Approach 4 works for me.  I'm not using custom namespaces inside though.  Just using standard `context:property-placeholder`.

Answer (score 5):

- On the context tag you can indicate that if a properties file does
  not exist it does not need to fail.
- Property files are loaded in the order that they are declared.  (This
  might also be a property to declare on the tag.  Not sure)
- If a property is declared multiple times, the last loaded value is
  used.

We use these three features as follows:

We declare two property files:

```
classpath:esb-project-config.properties,
classpath:esb-project-config-override.properties
```

The first property file contains sensible defaults and development configuration.  This file is part of your application.

The second property file is a file that is available on the test classpath or even the production classpath of the application server.  This file is **external** of the application
That way we can override properties for each environment and have just one version of our application.

So here is the example of the properties we use:

```
    <context:property-placeholder 
       ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" 
       location="classpath:esb-project-config.properties,classpath:esb-project-config-override.properties" />
```

Answer (score 4):

My preferred method, as added by spring 3.1, is as follows:

In your *-context.xml:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/web-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```

and in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

You can then specify the environment at runtime, for example:

```
mvn -Dspring.profiles.active=dev jetty:run
```

Or however you pass arguments to your container.

Answer (score 3):

It seems:

```
  <beans profile="dev">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/dev.properties"/>
  </beans>
  <beans profile="prod">
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/prod.properties"/>
  </beans>
```

It doesn't work. But you can do:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config_${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />
```

Comment: What doesn't work for you?  I'm doing exactly this in my application with no problems.

Comment: @Ryan I think the first didn't work for me, but I may be wrong. If I remember you can't put such a property placeholder tag inside a beans profile tag. Anyway, with Spring 3.1 the best is to register PropertySources in the environment and do not declare any local property files in the context imho

Comment: What technique are you using to register the PropertySources?  An initializer?  The property-placeholder tag should put the properties in the Environment.  That said, you may be right about the property-placeholder inside the 'beans' tag.  I made it work, but it seems to not behave properly when I have two different contexts with beans elements that have property-placeholders inside.  Might be related to this bug. https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9989

Comment: I use something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669474/load-properties-file-in-spring-depending-on-profile/14030098#14030098 It allows fine grained control on properties, and you can also add the properties to an Xml application context, just before the context is refreshed.