# Spring Multiple Environment Best Practices?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7, environment-variables

I have just taken on this project and its in an interesting state.  I am trying to establish a local, dev, and production environment.  I have it working and was curious to know if there is a better way or if the way I am doing it has risks.

Inside my Dispacher-Servlet.xml i have this line:
`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application_${spring.profiles.active}.properties" />`

Then I have a setenv.sh file that uses:
`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=local"`

Then inside of my controller to reference the variables I use:
`@PropertySource("classpath:application_${spring.profiles.active}.properties")`

Like I said it seems to work ok, it just doesn't seem to be what the documentation points you to do.

Comment: @B Rad, did you consider using Spring Profiles? here's a few other suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470551/spring-property-substitution-for-test-and-production

Comment: Oh, and there are ``maven`` profiles as well, which may be worth looking into if you're already using maven

Comment: I looked into profiles however it looked like I would need to duplicate a lot of the settings inside the dispatcher.  I had 3 different `beans` with different profile names but I couldn't figure out how to have a bean they all could share.  It seemed overly complex for what I was looking for.  The biggest problem with that approach was I couldn't figure out how to us it inside a controller.

Comment: Are you packaging all your environment properties file within the ear/war?

Comment: I have 5 different property files within the Resources directory.  I do not have a war directory in this project.  The structure of this project is foreign to me.