# Spring override properties based on environment

Tags: spring

Locally, I am reading in properties like this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="META-INF/dsk.properties" />
```

But in my test and production environments, I will have an `env`environment variable that's set to "test" or "prd", as well as `test.properties` and `prd.properties` how can I tell Spring to read an environment variable and set my properties file accordingly?

Comment: You can use profiling in Spring, check this http://memorynotfound.com/spring-profiles-java-xml-configuration/

Comment: You will find the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470551/spring-property-substitution-for-test-and-production